# How to add and later remove or disable a CSS rule in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to add and remove or disable a CSS rule in JavaScript? Here is the CSS:

```
#myElement *, #myElement *:before {
   outline:1px dotted red;
}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
var myCSS = "#myElement *, #myElement *:before {outline:1px dotted red;}";
// document.addCSS(myCSS);
```

**EDIT:**
I can't add the rules to the HTML page and toggle between them. I need to be able to create a rule in JavaScript after the page loads and also switch it on and off in JS.

Comment: your question is not clear.What is is the expected output?

Comment: My question is different than the one linked in that I must also be able to remove the rule (or disable it).

Comment: My question is different than the one marked as duplicate. My question asks how to remove or disable. The linked question does not provide that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you could find an answer here on Mozilla Developer Network:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule

> Inserts a new CSS rule into the current style sheet

Example:

```
// create a style sheet and add rule
var borderStyleSheet = document.createElement("style");
document.head.appendChild(borderStyleSheet);
borderStyleSheet.sheet.insertRule("#myElement *{ outline: 1px solid red;}", 0);

// disable rule
borderStyleSheet.disabled = true;

// enable rule
borderStyleSheet.disabled = false;

// see existing stylesheets
console.log(document.styleSheets);
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can add class using `className` property

```
document.getElementById("myElement").className += " MyClass";
```

you can add multiple class and remove class using `classList`

```
 document.getElementById("myElement").classList.add('newclass');

 document.getElementById("myElement").classList.remove('newclass');
```

Comment: The OP's question is how to turn the rule on or off.

Comment: @torazaburo :- he say remove later using any javascript condition...its not say toggling functionality right??

Answer (score 1):

The common way of doing this is to use a class to turn on/off the styles. As in:

```
#myElement.outline *, #myElement.outline *:before {
  outline:1px dotted red;
}
```

Then (in this example) you add/remove the `outline` class as needed via javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so as follows:

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
sheet.insertRule(".foo { color:pink; }", sheet.cssRules.length);
```

Except on internet explorer <= 8, where you must write

```
sheet.addRule(".foo", "color: pink;", -1);
```